How to disable all interaction with specific series in echarts?
I have this chart that has couple of lines that I want to function only as visual guideline, basically just some "background visuals". I don't want to have any interaction with it. I managed to remove all clicks/highlight and everything else except it still highlighting and snapping to data points when user moves the mouse.


Adding tooltip: {show: false} to the series seems to do the trick.
Example:
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [[1, 820], [3, 932], [5, 901], [7, 934], [9, 1290], [11, 1330], [13, 1320]],
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [[0, 300], [2, 300], [4, 300], [6, 300], [8, 300], [10, 300], [12, 300]],
      silent: true,
      tooltip: {show: false}
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [[0, 600], [2, 600], [4, 600], [6, 600], [8, 600], [10, 600], [12, 600]],
      silent: true,
      tooltip: {show: false}
    },
  ]
};


Thank you this was it. I think I tested out every property, maybe I missed this one, or didn't check the result of it.
